# Impossible to migrate from 4.0 to 5.0 in OneSignal. OSDeviceState is not working. I can not retrieve the title and the body of received notifications

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, onesignal

I use to run the OneSignal 4.0 with that code that worked well, but now, impossible to migrate to the 5.0. I cannot find the way to use OSDeviceState, and to get the title and the body of the received notification in the new 5.0

**OneSignal 4.0**

```
    OSDeviceState deviceState = OneSignal.getDeviceState(); //???
    
    OneSignal.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(notificationReceivedEvent -> {
            String title = notificationReceivedEvent.getNotification().getTitle();
            String body = notificationReceivedEvent.getNotification().getBody();
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.xxxx.xxxx.CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION");
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
           

    intent.putExtra("message", body);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        // ne pas afficher la notification dans le système de notification
        notificationReceivedEvent.complete(null);
    });
```

**OneSignal 5.0**

```
   // Verbose Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.
    OneSignal.getDebug().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this, ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);

    // requestPermission will show the native Android notification permission prompt.
    // NOTE: It's recommended to use a OneSignal In-App Message to prompt instead.
    OneSignal.getNotifications().requestPermission(true, Continue.with(r -> {
        if (r.isSuccess()) {
            if (r.getData()) {
                // `requestPermission` completed successfully and the user has accepted permission
            }
            else {
                // `requestPermission` completed successfully but the user has rejected permission
            }
        }
        else {
            // `requestPermission` completed unsuccessfully, check `r.getThrowable()` for more info on the failure reason
        }
    }));
```

Thanks in advance